# Invert soundsc function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, speech-processing

Does anyone know what is the inverse function of `soundsc` in matlab.

I'm playing a sound with a my PC microphone using `soundsc`, and I want to capture it in another PC using the inverse function.

Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

To decode in real time either:

1) Use the audiorecorder object suggested inside MBaz and use it's methods inside a loop to get collections of samples to decode in real time.

2) Take a look at this Simulink object http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/fromaudiodevice.html . It will output at the buffer size that you specify so that you can process it in real-time

3) Learn how to use MATLAB directly with your hardware.